# Progress Towards Insanity

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

*When the fever starts to spread this year, you're gonna need to call an expert!*

> FERUPTEMEFVOLCANIMEFMATERIAMEFINVOLVEMEFIMEFAMEFINDOOMEFCHILDRENMEFGAMME
>
> ILWAUKABETEASHELPBALLLAYASSISTRHOSSERVELUBASOORLDBOOSTRIESITLSUPPORTS
>
> DEMPRIVADINASDLEFADIRDELLAGULLYDWRETADCIMPOTARDCIDA
>
> REDENTIALINITUTIONPRINENTLYFEUREDWIINMAINCHNINSTOAWDWIINGMUCAL
>
> LIKECNAHCITINRARISENILTROHSORXATEMOCNILOADDKLAWDRAOBRVOLVRSLIAJNI [FF]
>
> DLTARNATEUAUTEWYPACALLYRFFAREDDSWHAUASULTRFFARFRASHESRRVLAWXRAFFIC
>
> EIVGIAEHTKSDOLCUTRHOULDESNYOTMNGURINDHILOCIASNJSATHERINGGTX
>
> YIORITLYMSTELMNTELNDPLEMENTELDNTHILNDOWDELDYERGENCLYSOMLS [MW]
>
> SPEBONTDHAIACTVOLYOENCURAQESANEGTSVEABEHVIYRSEVIKEDOMSDICLVIOEXCE
>
> SAMAUNTSRECAMMENDEDSFARSCANSUMPTIANSPERSSITTINGSACCARDINGSTASTHESFAADSPYRAMID [E]
>
> PNGPLURALIZELZIPALGIFNBLTXTSITCOLCSVSTARRINLEXETELWAVDANSOLRARALCOMSALMOVMALONL
>
> LYUSMSGUCOMPONERBUREFRIGERASGUMAGNDAUNEUPOPCSYUKERNEEUEFUTHSQUHAZA

The answer is a **twelve-letter thematic word**.

---

**Hint for extraction**

> If you've solved all the clues and have a sentence, then follow the instructions. The first letter clues a relation with the clue solutions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The 12-letter answer to this puzzle is:

> **BRACKETOLOGY**

Why? Read on, to find out!

---

Firstly, the 12 letter strings that we have been given are all clues that have been disguised. In each case, their decryption can be described by a very specific transformation, unique to each clue. Once deciphered, each clue leads us to a one-word answer. Then - crucially - once we have that one-word answer:

> That answer can then be manipulated by applying to it *the same specific transformation* that was used to encrypt its clue in the first place. The words that result from these transformations are all **nicknames of college basketball teams, plus one additional superfluous letter**.
>  <sub>(I owe this initial discovery to a very useful nudge from @Deusovi in the comments...)</sub>
>
>  This was hinted at in the puzzle title and flavourtext, as the day this puzzle was published marks the first day of **[March Madness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021_NCAA_Division_I_Men%27s_Basketball_Tournament)**, the annual college basketball competition in the US. The puzzle's title, 'Progress towards insanity', is very much a 'March (of) Madness', after all...

The complete set of transformed words is as follows:

> 1. LAVA → FLA(V)ME
>  2. BREWER → RAID(W)ER
>  3. HACK → D(H)UCK
>  4. ORPHANAGE → ORAN(A)GE
>  5. BULLETED → BULL(T)DOG
>  6. DETOUR → GATO(U)R
>  7. SHUN → (N)HUSKY
>  8. TRIAGE → E(I)AGLE
>  9. ENABLER → BE(N)AVER
>  10. PORTION → SPART(I)AN
>  11. CHEER → TAR(C)HEEL
>  12. CHOKING → GAUCHO(K)

Explanations for decrypting the original strings:

1. FERUPTEMEFVOLCANIMEFMATERIAMEFINVOLVEMEFIMEFAMEFINDOOMEFCHILDRENMEFGAMME

> This is a sequence of words where three things have been done to each one: (i) an 'F' has been added to the front, (ii) the last letter of the word has been changed to an 'M', and (iii) an 'E' has been added to the end. Thus, we have:
>
>  F**ERUPTEd**E F**VOLCANIc**E F**MATERIAl**E F**INVOLVEd**E F**In**E F**An**E F**INDOOr**E F**CHILDRENs**E F**GAMe**E
>
>  This clues **LAVA** as in the indoor children's game, 'Floor Is Lava'. Applying the same transformation to 'LAVA' gives us '**FLAVME**, the word 'FLAME' (as in Liberty Flames) with an additional '**V**'...

2. ILWAUKABETEASHELPBALLLAYASSISTRHOSSERVELUBASOORLDBOOSTRIESITLSUPPORTS

> As noted by @Mohirl and @samm82, this letter sequence contains many synonyms for the word 'AID':
>
>  ILWAUK**ABET**EAS**HELP**BALLLAY**ASSIST**RHOS**SERVE**LUBASOORLD**BOOST**RIESITL**SUPPORT**S
>
>  If we replace each of these words with the letter 'E' we end up with a concatenated series of words that are missing their first letters. From these we can work out the intended clue as:
>
>  mILWAUK**E**E bAS**E**BALL pLAY**E**R wHOS**E** cLUB hAS nO wORLD s**E**RIES tITL**E**S
>
>  This clues the word **BREWER**, as the Milwaukee Brewers are an MLB team who have never won the World Series. If we then replace the first 'E' with 'AID' and remove the first letter, we get **RAIDWER**: the word 'RAIDER' (as in Colgate Raiders) with an additional '**W**'...

3. DEMPRIVADINASDLEFADIRDELLAGULLYDWRETADCIMPOTARDCIDA

> This string is a concatenation of words preceded by the letter 'D', and where each vowel needs to be moved along one in the looping vowel sequence A-E-I-O-U-A, like so:
>
>  D|**I**MPR**O**V**E**|D|**O**N**E**S|D|L**I**F**E**|D|**O**R|D|**I**LL**E**G**A**LLY|D|WR**I**T**E**|D|C**O**MP**U**T**E**R|D|C**O**D**E**
>
>  The clue 'IMPROVE ONE'S LIFE OR ILLEGALLY WRITE COMPUTER CODE' leads us to the word '**HACK**. If we prefix this with a 'D' and move the 'A' back in the chain to 'U', we end up with '**DHUCK**', which is the word 'DUCK' (as in Oregon Ducks) with an additional '**H**'...

4. REDENTIALINITUTIONPRINENTLYFEUREDWIINMAINCHNINSTOAWDWIINGMUCAL

> Here we have a concatenated string of words which are all missing their third and fourth letters:
>  RE**SI**DENTIAL IN**ST**ITUTION PR**OM**INENTLY FE**AT**URED WI**TH**IN MA**RT**IN CH**AR**NIN'S TO**NY** AW**AR**D WI**NN**ING MU**SI**CAL
>
>  The only Martin Charnin musical that has ever *won* a Tony was *Annie* in 1977. This takes place largely in an **ORPHANAGE**. Removing the third and fourth letters gives us **ORANAGE**: the word 'ORANGE' (as in Syracuse Orange) with an additional '**A**'...

5. LIKECNAHCITINRARISENILTROHSORXATEMOCNILOADDKLAWDRAOBRVOLVRSLIAJNI [FF]

> Reading this string *backwards* we can spot the names of several squares on the US Monopoly board:
>
>  LIK**ECNAHC**ITINRARIS**ENILTROHS**OR**XATEMOCNI**LOADD**KLAWDRAOB**RVOLVRS**LIAJNI** [FF]
>  (In Jail, Boardwalk, Income Tax, Short Line, Chance)
>
>  If we *remove* these, we are left with the chunks:
>  LIK ITINRARIS OR LOADD RVOLVRS [FF]
>
>  Adding the letter 'E' into obvious positions in this yields:
>  LIKE ITINERARIES OR LOADED REVOLVERS
>
>  This suggests the answer **BULLETED** (itineraries have bullet points, loaded revolvers have bullets!). If we remove the letter E's and add 'OG' (backwards 'GO', from the Monopoly board) to the end of it, we get **BULLTDOG**: the word 'BULLDOG' (as in Drake/Gonzaga Bulldogs) with an additional '**T**'...
>
>  Furthermore, here the presence of the '[FF]' at the end of the encrypted string is intended to help us resolve the ambiguity in there being two teams in this year's contest with this nickname. 'FF' here stands for '**F**irst **F**our', the name of the round in this year's tournament in which *Drake* Bulldogs first competed, meaning that team is the one we require. (We will see soon why it is important to differentiate between the two teams with the same nickname in this way...)

6. DLTARNATEUAUTEWYPACALLYRFFAREDDSWHAUASULTRFFARFRASHESRRVLAWXRAFFIC

> With thanks to @Deusovi in comments (who formalised my discovery into an actual formulaic substitution process), this is a string of words that have had (i) their first letter shifted forwards in the alphabet by 3 letter positions, and (ii) their first vowel replaced by the letter 'A'. If we break the string up thus:
>  DLTARNATE UAUTE WYPACALLY RFFARED DS W HAUASULT RF FAR FRASHES RR VLAW XRAFFIC
>
>  ...we can generate the alternative sentence:
>  **A**LT**E**RNATE **RO**UTE **T**YP**I**CALLY **O**FF**E**RED **A**S **T**H**E** **RE**SULT **O**F **C**AR **C**RASHES **O**R **S**L**O**W **T**RAFFIC
>
>  This suggests the answer **DETOUR**. Moving the leading 'D' on 3 spaces and replacing the 'E' with an 'A' yields '**GATOUR**', i.e. the word 'GATOR' (as in Florida Gators) with an additional '**U**'...

7. EIVGIAEHTKSDOLCUTRHOULDESNYOTMNGURINDHILOCIASNJSATHERINGGTX

> Big hat-tip to @Mohirl on this one, who parsed the sentence before me - the sentence can be split into letter chunks, each suffixed by a US state abbreviation:
>
>  EIVG **IA** EHT **KS** DOLC **UT** RHOULDES **NY** OT **MN** GURIND **HI** LOCIAS **NJ** SATHERINGG **TX**
>
>  Notice that you can then swap the first and last letters of each of the sections between the chunks to make real words:
>  GIVE THE COLD SHOULDER TO DURING SOCIAL GATHERINGS
>
>  This clues the word '**SHUN**', which with the first-last letter swap and the addition of KY (Kentucky) becomes '**NHUSKY**', i.e. the word 'HUSKY' (as in UConn Huskies) with an additional '**N**'...

8. YIORITLYMSTELMNTELNDPLEMENTELDNTHILNDOWDELDYERGENCLYSOMLS [MW]

> This took a while to spot, but if we split up the string like so:
>  YIORITLY MSTELM NTELN DPLEMENTELD NTHILN DOWDELD YERGENCLY SOMLS [MW]
>
>  *then* we can spot a pattern - this is a series of words where (i) the first two letters have been removed and replaced with the *last* letter of the word, and (ii) an 'L' has been inserted before the last letter. Decoding this gives us:
>  PRIORITY SYSTEM OFTEN IMPLEMENTED WITHIN CROWDED EMERGENCY ROOMS.
>
>  The answer is therefore '**TRIAGE**', which becomes **EIAGLE** by following the same rules. This is the word 'EAGLE' (as in Winthrop Eagles, Eastern Washington Eagles, and Morehead State Eagles) with an additional '**I**'...
>
>  The '[MW]' at the end of the string is provided to help differentiate which of the three 'Eagles' teams is required for the solution of the puzzle. The team taking part in the **M**id**W**est Regional section of the tournament is *Morehead State* Eagles (note this for later).

9. SPEBONTDHAIACTVOLYOENCURAQESANEGTSVEABEHVIYRSEVIKEDOMSDICLVIOEXCE

> In this string we have a series of words that have been manipulated by (i) moving their fourth letter to the front of the word, and then (ii) shifting the third letter from the end 10 places onward in the alphabet (looping from Z to A as required). If we split the string like so:
>
>  SPEBON TDHA IACTVOLY OENCURAQES ANEGTSVE ABEHVIYRS EVIK EDOMSDIC LVIOEXCE
>
>  Then we can translate this by the rules set out above to:
>
>  PERSON THAT ACTIVELY ENCOURAGES NEGATIVE BEHAVIORS LIKE DOMESTIC VIOLENCE
>
>  This defines the word '**ENABLER**'. If we then move its fourth letter (B) to the front and shift its third-to-last letter (L) forward by 10 alphabet positions, we get '**BENAVER**', which is the word 'BEAVER' (as in Oregon State Beavers) with an additional '**N**'...

10. SAMAUNTSRECAMMENDEDSFARSCANSUMPTIANSPERSSITTINGSACCARDINGSTASTHESFAADSPYRAMID [E]

> Here, every 'O' has been replaced by an 'A', and every word has been preceded by an 'S'. The sentence should read:
>  AMOUNT RECOMMENDED FOR CONSUMPTION PER SITTING ACCORDING TO THE FOOD PYRAMID [E]
>
>  This reference to the [food pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_pyramid_(nutrition)) leads us to **PORTION**. If we replace its O's with A's and add an 'S' at the start, this gives us **SPARTIAN**, which is the word 'SPARTAN' (as in UNC Greensboro, Norfolk Stae, and Michigan State Spartans) with an additional '**I**'...
>
>  To remove ambiguity, the '[E]' provided at the end of the string suggests we need to choose the team playing in the **E**ast Regional section of the tournament - this is *UNC Greensboro* Spartans.

11. PNGPLURALIZELZIPALGIFNBLTXTSITCOLCSVSTARRINLEXETELWAVDANSOLRARALCOMSALMOVMALONL

> This comprises a series of words whose last letters have been changed to 'L', and which are all preceded by common 3-letter file extensions:
>
>  **.PNG** PLURALIZEL **.ZIP** AL **.GIF** NBL **.TXT** SITCOL **.CSV** STARRINL **.EXE** TEL **.WAV** DANSOL **.RAR** AL **.COM** SAL **.MOV** MALONL
>
>  Correcting the last letters gives the clue:
>  PLURALIZE**D**, A**N** NB**C** SITCO**M** STARRIN**G** TE**D** DANSO**N** A**S** SA**M** MALON**E**.
>
>  The sitcom is *Cheers*, so the answer we need is **CHEER**. If we add the .TAR file extension to the front and change the final 'R' to an 'L', we get 'TARCHEEL', which is 'TAR HEEL' (as in North Carolina Tar Heels) with an additional '**C**'...

12. LYUSMSGUCOMPONERBUREFRIGERASGUMAGNDAUNEUPOPCSYUKERNEEUEFUTHSQUHAZA

> Here, we can split the string into several sections beginning with 3 seemingly nonsensical letters (the last of which is always a 'U') which appear to be corruptions of real words:
>  LYU**SM** SGU**COMPONE** RBU**REFRIGERA** SGU**MAGN** DAU NEU**POPC** SYU**KERN** EEU EFU**TH** SQU**HAZA**
>
>  What's going on here, and what are these 'nonsense' letters? Well, it appears that each of the chunks after the 'nonsense' is a word missing its three last letters. Then the first letter of the 'nonsense' section is the word's original last letter, moved to its front; the second is the word's original second-to-last letter but rot-13'd (shifted 13 places along in the alphabet); and the third is just 'U'. With this in mind, we can parse the sentence as:
>  SM**ALL** COMPONE**NTS**, REFRIGERA**TOR** MAGN**ETS** **AND** POPC**ORN** KERN**ELS** **ARE** TH**ESE** HAZA**RDS**
>
>  This clues **CHOKING**, which can then be transformed by the same mechanism into '**GAUCHOK**', which is 'GAUCHO' (as in UC Santa Barbara Gauchos) with an additional '**K**'...

Now that we know all 12 surplus letters, what do we do next?

> The surplus letters spell '**VWHATUNINICK**'. This needs to be parsed as "**V WHAT UNI NICK?**",  and we must then interpret it as a requirement for us to find out ***WHAT** is the **NICK**name of the **UNI**versity team that each of these teams played (i.e. '**V**' for 'versus') in their first match of this year's tournament*.

So taking our list of answers, these would be:

> 1. [Liberty] FLA(V)ME vs [Oklahoma State] **COWBOYS**
>  2. [Colgate] RAID(W)ER vs [Arkansas] **RAZORBACKS**
>  3. [Oregon] D(H)UCK vs [VCU] **RAMS**
>  4. [Syracuse] ORAN(A)GE vs [San Diego State] **AZTECS**
>  5. [Drake] BULL(T)DOG vs [Wichita State] **SHOCKERS**
>  6. [Florida] GATO(U)R vs [Virginia Tech] **HOKIES**
>  7. [UConn] (N)HUSKY vs [Maryland] **TERRAPINS**
>  8. [Morehead State] E(I)AGLE vs [West Virginia] **MOUNTAINEERS**
>  9. [Oregon State] BE(N)AVER vs [Tennessee] **VOLUNTEERS**
>  10. [UNC Greensboro] SPART(I)AN vs [Florida State] **SEMINOLES**
>  11. [North Carolina] TAR(C)HEEL vs [Wisconsin] **BADGERS**
>  12. [UC Santa Barbara] GAUCHO(K) vs [Creighton] **BLUEJAYS**

Finally, there is one more step to extracting the final answer:

> We must index into the opposing team nicknames, looking at the same position in their name as is occupied by the superfluous letter in the names of the teams we've already found. This gives us:
>
>  1. FLA(V)ME → COW(**B**)OYS
>  2. RAID(W)ER → RAZO(**R**)BACKS
>  3. D(H)UCK → R(**A**)MS
>  4. ORAN(A)GE → AZTE(**C**)S
>  5. BULL(T)DOG → SHOC(**K**)ERS
>  6. GATO(U)R → HOKI(**E**)S
>  7. (N)HUSKY → (**T**)ERRAPINS
>  8. E(I)AGLE → M(**O**)UNTAINEERS
>  9. BE(N)AVER → VO(**L**)UNTEERS
>  10. SPART(I)AN → SEMIN(**O**)LES
>  11. TAR(C)HEEL → BAD(**G**)ERS
>  12. GAUCHO(K) → BLUEJA(**Y**)S
>
>  And these letters in order spell **BRACKETOLOGY**, defined by [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/what-does-bracketology-mean) as "*the practice or study of predicting the outcome of an elimination tournament or competition.*"
>
>  Many people following March Madness 2021 and trying to predict the outcome of each match in order to win big in the usual sweepstakes that run alongside the tournament is no doubt desperate to be proved an *expert* (see the initial puzzle flavourtext) in *this* field!

Comment: The transformations used are important! Specifically, ([rot13](http://rot13.com))vs lbh nccyl rnpu genafsbezngvba gb gur pbeerfcbaqvat pyhr'f nafjre, lbh trg fbzrguvat ryfr. Urer, vg'f n fgevat gung nccrnef gb or n onfxrgonyy grnz, cyhf bar yrggre: SYNIZR, ENVQJRE, GNEPURRY...

Comment: @Deusovi OH! Then this is all leading us towards rot13(Znepu Znqarff) - especially with the title!

Comment: Oh, of course! I didn't even consider that.

Comment: For 6, the transformation isn't random - I believe it's "Caesar-shift the first letter back by 3, and replace the first vowel with A"?

Comment: @Deusovi Yes, now that you point this out I'm sure that much of my 'random' descriptives are actually very carefully chosen indeed! Time to go over this with an even finer toothcomb...

Comment: You all are making fantastic progress BTW, let me know if any of you need an additional hint to keep it going

Comment: I think I have a possibility for #12, though I don't know enough about the subject to fully flesh it out. rot13(Lbh'ir nyernql abgrq gung zbfg bs gur ercynprzrag guerr yrggref raq va H - guvf zvtug vaqvpngr n havirefvgl. Gur bayl bar gung whzcf bhg gb zr vf FLH ng gur raq bs cbcpbea. Gur Flenphfr havirefvgl grnz vf Benatr, naq gur yrggref ercynprq yrggref ol FLH ner BEA. Gur bgure frgf bs ercynprq yrggref qb nyy ybbx yvxr gurl pbhyq or cneg bs n grnz avpxanzr, r.t. rRYF, ubeaRGF, ohg V qba'g xabj jurer gb fgneg vqragvslvat HF pbyyrtr onfxrgonyy grnzf.)

Comment: @Mohirl Funnily enough I literally just worked out number 12! (Writing up now...) I got stuck for ages thinking the 'U' might relate to 'University', but it's another tricksy substitution one - posting shortly...!

Comment: Lol! I was going to say the only thing I could see in common rot13(orgjrra sevqtr zntargf naq cbcpbea xrearyf jnf gung gurl'er obgu pubxvat unmneqf! Qvqa'g frrz eryrinag gubhtu.)

Comment: @Stiv The solution to no. 7 is OEH(E)VA, juvpu vf OHEE (flabalz bs FAHO) jvgu gur svefg naq ynfg yrggref fjnccrq naq VA (Vaqvnan) nqqrq gb gur raq. Hope this helps you solve the puzzle!

Comment: @TakingNotes Hang on, isn't that the wrong way round? Shouldn't the middle of the word stay constant, and the first-last letters swap places? I think I considered this word already and hit that mental dead end before so discarded it (I've considered so many words for this one!). Have I got things the wrong way round here??

Comment: @TakingNotes Good idea, but rot13(nccylvat gur genafsbezngvba gb gur jbeq lbh fhttrfg erfhygf va EHEOVA vafgrnq bs gung, cyhf V qba'g guvax OHEE vf n fbyhgvba gb gur bevtvany pyhr hayrff gurer'f na nepunvp zrnavat V qba'g xabj nobhg.) Since you all are struggling a bit here with that specific string, I'll let you all know that Stiv has rot13(nyernql fhttrfgrq gur pbeerpg fgnegvat jbeq va gurve fbyhgvba; vg zvtug uryc gb ybbx ng gur yvfg bs nyy cbffvoyr gurzngvp nafjref gb svther vg bhg)

Comment: @HTM Is this team definitely competing this year? I swear I've been over the list so many times. I'm probably just not seeing the wood for the trees right now...! :)

Comment: @HTM Never mind - just got it. It's a team whose singular is not spelled the same as their plural!

Comment: @HTM the funny thing is i have been over the list so many times and when i spotted the similarities between OHEE and OEHVA something just went "yea this seems right"...

Comment: @HTM Is the answer rot13(IBYHAGRRE) or am I barking up the wrong tree? (Or in the wrong forest altogether...?)

Comment: @Stiv Not what I had in mind. In particular, rot13(gur svefg yrggre bs gubfr gjryir fhecyhf yrggref qbrf abg vaqvpngr n fcrpvsvp fpubby, gubhtu V jba'g fnl jung vg npghnyyl zrnaf evtug abj.) Also, there's some bracketed letters next to the original strings that need to be addressed...

Comment: Actually, I'm going to add a length requirement for the final answer to hopefully provide a hint as to how to get to it while shutting down alternative paths - in the meantime, I hope you're still having fun with this puzzle!

Comment: @Stiv I have added a hint for the extraction phase of the puzzle, hope it's helpful!

Comment: @HTM So my latest thoughts are that rot13(gur 'I' ercerfragf 'irefhf' naq jr'er fhccbfrq gb ybbx ng gur HAV AVPXanzrf bs gur grnzf CYNLRQ ol gur grnzf va gur chmmyr va gur svefg ebhaq bs gur gbheanzrag. Ubjrire, V'z trggvat abafrafr ntnva jura V pbafvqre gur pbeerfcbaqvat avpxanzrf' vavgvnyf: P(EN)ENFUG(JWZ)I(FZO)OO. Ehaavat bhg bs vqrnf va nyy ubarfgl!)

Comment: @Stiv Have you tried rot13(ybbxvat ng gur ybpngvbaf bs gur rkgen yrggref?)

Comment: @HTM Got it! Will write up as soon as kids' bedtimes are done! (Had tried both 'parts' of the final extraction, but never *together*!)

Comment: You got it, congrats! One minor thing: rot13(va lbhe rkcynangvba bs gur genafsbezngvba sbe gur fgevat fgnegvat YLHFZ, gur jbeq GUERR fubhyq npghnyyl or GURFR); besides that, great explanation of the steps!

Comment: @HTM Correction made! Great puzzle - went much deeper (and much longer!) than I ever expected when I started trying to work it out!

Answer (score 2):

Very partial, but for at least some of the lines

> We can make coherent sentences using various letter substitutions. All of the resulting sentences seem to be straightforward clues.

FERUPTEMEFVOLCANIMEFMATERIAMEFINVOLVEMEFIMEFAMEFINDOOMEFCHILDRENMEFGAMME

> Replacing EF with spaces gives us FERUPTEM VOLCANIM MATERIAM INVOLVEM IM AM INDOOM CHILDRENM GAMME, which seems be the sentence ERUPTED VOLCANIC MATERIAL INVOLVED IN AN INDOOR CHILDRENS GAME but with most of the last letters replaced with M. Which seems to be a clue to HOT LAVA.

ILWAUKABETEASHELPBALLLAYASSISTRHOSSERVELUBASOORLDSBOOSTRIESITLSUPPORTS

> Contains a number of synonyms - HELP, ASSIST, SERVE, BOOST, SUPPORT. The initial ILWAUK beings Milwaukee to mind, might just be coincidence.

REDENTIALINITUTIONPRINENTLYFEUREDWIINMAINCHNINSTOAWDWIINGMUCAL

> Add in a lot of pairs of missing letters, and we get RESIDENTIAL INSTITUTION PROMINENTLY FEATURED WITHIN MAINCHNINSTO???? AWARD WINNING MUSICAL, the missing pairs being SI ST OM AT TH ??? AR NN SI. Seems to be another clue, not sure of the answer.

EIVGIAEHTKSDOLCUTRHOULDESNYOTMNGURINDHILOCIASNJSATHERINGGTX

> If we ignore some letters and treat them as spaces, we end up with GIVE THE COLD SHOULDER TO DURING SOCIAL GATHERING individually anagrammed. The ignored letters are IA KS UT NY MN HI NJ TX. The clue answer might be IGNORE, which is interesting since we've ignored some letters. Also those letters seem to clue US states

SAMAUNTSRECAMMENDEDSFARSCANSUMPTIANSPERSSITTINGSACCARDINGSTASTHESFAADSPYRAMID [E]

> Replace most of the As with O, and S with space, and we get AMOUNT RECOMMENDED FOR CONSUMPTION PER SITTING ACCORDING TO THE FOOD PYRAMID

I can't see an overall pattern though

Comment: The one beginning REDENTIAL should be rot13(ERFVQRAGVNY VAFGVGHGVBA CEBZVARAGYL SRNGHERQ JVGUVA ZNEGVA PUNEAVAF GBAL NJNEQ JVAAVAT ZHFVPNY) - always the third and fourth letters are missing in a word. The musical referred to is rot13(NAAVR) so presumably the institution is rot13(BECUNANTR)? I have a few other lines partially solved already too, but won't post until I have them resolved fully...

Comment: Some observations: the second one also contains rot13(NORG), and the last one might clue rot13(FREIVAT)